# Challenging Problems in Geometry 4-24 challenge

Tags: geometry

So I have been working on this geometry problem in the book mentioned in the title, and it doesn't have solutions to all the problems. I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.

Two circles are tangent externally at T. Chord TM in circle O is perpendicular to chord TN in circle Q. Show that MN = $ \sqrt{2(R^2+r^2)}$ if the circles are unequal, where R and r are the radii of the two circles.

Comment: The given answer makes no sense. It will depend on the angle of $TM,TN$ to the axis of symmetry of the two circles.

Comment: Thank you. I literally copied word for word onto this website, and I was having a really difficult time.

Comment: The answer is only correct when the cords have an angle of $45^\circ$ with respect to the axis of symmetry.